# jQuery .height() or outterheight() returning values larger than actual element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to loop through all the elements that has the class svg_hover and get the height of them. However It's seemingly giving me impossible heights for example if you look at the image the correct height of this element is 305 but it's giving me 327. And it get's worse occasionally it will give me numbers in the 600's.

[image]

here is my code.

```
var el = $('.svg_hover')

  $(document).ready( ()=> {

    el.each(function ( idx ) {
      let e = $(this),
          content_height = e.outerHeight();

      console.log(e, content_height);

    })
  })
```

Comment: [outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) includes the margin among other things. Are you sure it's the value you're looking for? How about just width()?

Comment: yeah i'm adjusting the height of my svg path using relative to the height of my div so I was gonna get the height() or outterHeight() of the parent element but it's returning weird results.

Comment: Can you give us a working demo with your HTML and svg's?

Answer (score 3):

Try calling outerHeight in a $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() as $(window).load() waits for all elements, such as images, to be loaded before computing the height unlike $(document).ready() which might compute it too early

Comment: damn. I thought I tried this already but I was using $(document).load().
This worked

Comment: Hah no problem it happens

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking the `outerHeight()` you also get the padding and the border (`outerHight(true)` also gets the margin
), check for padding of the element and reset it `padding:0px`

[image]

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/